# How can i compressed(winrar) a file using command prompt and the file name of the .rar is the same with the file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, compression, winrar

i have a autoback.bat file that will automatically backup my database and compress in using winrar application. the problem is i cannot create a rar file that is the same filename of my database. for example, my database name is AutoBackup-Monday.bak. i should have AutoBackup-Monday.rar. i ahve a solution on this which needed 7 autoback.bat file. i want to have only 1 autoback.bat file to create on the daily basis.

This is my script named Voucherbackup11AM:

@ECHO OFF

rem

del z:\MBWin\autoback\BACKUP*.bak
del z:\MBWin\autoback\BACKUP\VoucherAutoBack11AM.rar

ECHO Database is backing up ... (mass_specc_voucher)

sqlcmd -S jem\mbwin -d master -U sa -i "z:\MBWin\AUTOBACK\voucherBackup11AM.sql"  -o VoucherBackup11AM.log

ECHO ----------------------------------------
ECHO ****   Backup Done, Please Verify   ****
ECHO ----------------------------------------

rem

z:\MBWin\AUTOBACK\winrar -ep a -ag-A z:\MBWin\AUTOBACK\BACKUP\VoucherAutoBack11AM.rar z:\MBWin\AUTOBACK\BACKUP*.bak
del z:\MBWin\autoback\BACKUP*.bak

PAUSE

The Output of my sql query is VoucherAutoBack11AM-Saturday.bak.
When I ran this script the output is VoucherAutoBack11AM-1.rar. What i want is VocuherAutoback11AM-Saturday.rar.

Comment: Edit your post & include your script so that people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

With WinRAR you simple tell it what you want it to be called.

`rar -a AutoBackup-Monday.rar AutoBackup-Monday.bak`

Would create a rar file with the name you are requesting. If you are doing this via a script, place your variable in there instead `rar -a %BACKUPFILE%.rar %BACKUPFILE%`

Comment: thank you for your answer sir. i edited my post n i posted my script.